# Laravel Schedule command Not worked on shared host with corn jobs

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I used Cornjob to execute the schedule:run command, but I get the following error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting
> identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in
> /home/xyz/project/artisan on line 33

Laravel Ver : 10
server php: 8.1

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/xyz/project/artisan && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Are you sure it's 8.1? Try `/usr/local/bin/php -v` on the command line. Also, you have some extra stuff there. Remove `&& php artisan`.  `&&` separates out the commands, so the left side is running artisan without any arguments, and right side is trying to run the artisan command in the cron user's home directory with the default php

Comment: @aynber I use a shared host and use the @dd(phpversion()) command.
I saw the php version 8.1.
Also, in cpanel, Php version is 8.1 I tried the way you suggested and it didn't fix the problem

Comment: You can have separate versions of PHP on the web and command line. Some shared hosts still allow command-line or shell access, so see if they offer it.